# php form doesn't send content after php version upgrade

Tags: php, forms, upgrade

My client made upgrade of PHP version in his website and now contact form in his website doesn't send content of emails. User get email but only with footer part with info from which system was email send but content miss.

How can I solve it?

```
<?php
    require_once("CMS/library/framework.php");
    require_once("CMS/library/standalone.inc.php");

    $id = intval($_POST["id"]);

    $lastname = $_POST["nachname"];
    $firstname = $_POST["vorname"];
    $company = $_POST["firma"];
    $street = $_POST["strasse"];
    $city = $_POST["ort"];
    $plz = $_POST["plz"];
    $tel = $_POST["telefon"];
    $email = $_POST["mail"];
    $message = $_POST["msg"];
    $captcha = $_POST["captcha"];

    // error handling
    $c = new captcha;
    $errors = "";
    if(empty($lastname)) $errors .= "Bitte geben Sie Ihren Nachnamen an.<br />";
    if(empty($firstname)) $errors .= "Bitte geben Sie Ihren Vornamen an.<br />";
    if(empty($street)) $errors .= "Bitte geben Sie Ihre Straße an.<br />";
    if(empty($plz)) $errors .= "Bitte geben Sie Ihre PLZ an.<br />";
    if(empty($city)) $errors .= "Bitte geben Sie Ihren Wohnort an.<br />";
    if(!is_valid_email_address($email)) $errors .= "Bitte geben Sie eine gültige E-Mail Adresse an.<br />";
    if(!$c->check($captcha)) $errors .= "Sie haben den Sicherheitscode falsch eingegeben.<br />";

    // get seminar
    $query = $db->query("SELECT titel FROM ".prefix."_seminare WHERE id = '$id'");
    $row = $db->fetch_assoc($query);
    $seminar = $row["titel"];       

    // error handling
    if(!empty($errors)){
        die($errors);
    }else{
        // sendmail
        $mail = new mail;
        $mail->from = $globalmailfrom;
        //$mail->to = $globalmailto;
        $mail->to = "praguedev@gmail.com";
        $mail->replyto = $email;
        $mail->subject = "Neue Seminaranmeldung";
        $mail->message = "Es liegt eine neue Seminaranmeldung vor!

        Seminar: $seminar

        Name: $firstname $lastname
        E-Mail: $email
        Firma: $company
        Straße: $street
        Ort: $plz $city
        Telefon: $tel       

        $message";          
        $mail->send();      

        // bestätigung
        $mail->to = $email;
        $mail->replyto = $globalmailfrom;
        $mail->subject = "Ihre Seminaranmeldung bei COWIMO";
        $mail->message = "Sehr geehrte/r $firstname $name,

        hiermit best&auml;tigen wir Ihnen die Buchung des Seminars $seminar.
        Weitere Informationen erhalten Sie in Kürze per E-Mail.

        Ihr COWIMO-Team.";
        $mail->send();
    }

    header("location: seminare_$id.php?action=buchen&success=success");
?>
```

**Email appearance - content is missing**

[image]

**I get the following errors:**

> Notice: Undefined variable: name in /www/htdocs/w00c7e22/seminarbuchung.php on line 80 Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /www/htdocs/w00c7e22/seminarbuchung.php:80) in /www/htdocs/w00c7e22/seminarbuchung.php on line 86

**The lines on PHP file:**

[image]

Comment: What is the $db object initiated with? Are you using the mysql_* functions? Try to use `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1)` to show up php errors.

Comment: you are sending two mails here.  Seems you have a custom mail class, can you post that code? ALso just as @Marcel said, add display errors. Thats the only way to locate errors. If not, you are writing blindly

Comment: Thank you guys.

I got these errors:

`Notice: Undefined variable: name in /www/htdocs/w00c7e22/seminarbuchung.php on line 80`

`Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /www/htdocs/w00c7e22/seminarbuchung.php:80) in /www/htdocs/w00c7e22/seminarbuchung.php on line 86`

Here is link on pic with numer of line. [link]https://ctrlv.cz/shots/2017/04/26/tP0y.png

Thank you!

Comment: added the details from comments.

Comment: I only see the variables $firstname and $lastname. The name variable is undefined. You should define the name variable: $name = $firstname.' '.$lastname;